# How to get a large integer as input and store it in memory

Tags: memory, input, portability, brainfuck

I know that performing arithmetic on large integers in brainfuck, while perhaps quite tedious at times, is entirely possible.

However what I'm wondering about is what the generally acceptd best-practices are for taking in large integers (or even strings, I suppose) as input.

Most compilers/interpreters allow you to provide full strings at once as input (and then each character is read in individually with a `,`). But what I'm wondering is this - how can you read one in if you don't know when the input stream is going to stop? I suppose one way is to tell the user to append a certain character/string of characters to their number to indicate that it's over, but that seems a bit non-user-friendly.

I'd prefer an answer that keeps portability in mind (implementation-specific solutions are of interest, but are not the primary focus of this question). If there is no completely implementation-agnostic way to do this, one that will work on most implementations and fail gracefully otherwise would be the next best thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're writing brainfuck code and are concerned about user-friendliness??

Comment: Wouldn't enter be a reasonable char to identify the end of input?

Comment: @Mau: That's a good idea. Not sure why that never came to mind. What about this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck#End-of-file_behavior ...just came accross that. I'm looking at the part that says you should set the cell to 0 before taking in input, and that if the cell is still 0, that means end of input on most implementations. Does that seem like a good way to go about this?

Comment: @incrediman: Umm, EOF in console input is less user-friendly because it requires the user to press Ctrl-Z or Ctrl-D.

Comment: @Mau yeah, nvm. I think you're right; newline's probably the best way to go about this. Thanks!

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain their reasoning? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most languages let you read a line from input (e.g. gets() in C, ReadLine() in C# etc). Why not ask the user to enter each value as a line (i.e. separated by enter)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had posted the same code for a different question for a different purpose.
Here following code will keep on accepting the ASCII of whatever you type unless a newline character is met.Then prints what you typed.

**Don't worry about the portability**; I've already implemented addition of two n-digit numbers with this strategy of reading numbers, you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670510/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-2-numbers-with-brainfuck/19412942#19412942).

```
> +
[ - >,>+< 
  ----- -----    ; minus 10
  [              ; if enters means it is not a \n
    +++++ +++++  ; restore prev value
    < 
  ] >>           ; moving forward
]
                 ; numbers are 0 0 49 0 50 0 51
                 ; for input 123
<<<<[<<]         ; moving to the beginning
>>               ; reaching first char
[.>>]            ; just printing till end
```