# Reading command line argument in Brainfuck

Tags: brainfuck

Can anyone help me to interpret command line arguments in Brainfuck program (if possible) as other languages like C read them? For example

`gcc cmd.c arg1 arg2`

I have installed the following interpreter on my Ubuntu machine-

> bf - a Brainfuck interpreter       version 20041219 (C) 2003, 2004,
>   Stephan Beyer, GPL, s-beyer@gmx.net

Is the following possible traditionally or with some hack?

`bf cmd.bf arg1 arg2`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
echo arg1 arg2 | bf cmd.bf
```

Then, your cmd.bf will have to handle/interpret the input and process it.

Comment: hey erdal, Thank you for your response. Can you please give a sample to add two integer arguments by cmd.bf? 

For example-  
echo 1 1 | bf cmd.bf

that will print "2" as output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670510/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-2-numbers-with-brainfuck

Answer (score 0):

I advise anyone getting started with BrainFuck should write the C implementation of the code you have in mind. To learn more https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck

The C implementation of your question will look like this

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    char array[20];

    array[0] = 8;
    array[1] = 51;
    array[2] = 50;
    while (array[0] != 0)
    {
        array[1] -= 6;
        array[2] -= 6;
        array[0]--;
    }
    array[1]++;
    while (array[1] != 0)
    {
        while (array[2] != 0)
        {
            array[3]++;
            array[4]++;
            array[2]--;
        }
        while (array[3] != 0)
        {
            array[2]++;
            array[3]--;
        }
        array[1]--;
    }
    
    array[0] = 8;
    while (array[0] != 0)
    {
        array[4] += 6;
        array[0]--;
    }
    
    putchar(array[4]);

}
```

then you can move over to the BrainFuck code which is this

```
++++ ++++               Cell c0 = 8
>,                      Reads input and stores in c1
>,                    Reads input and stores in c2
<<                     Moves to c0
[
    >--- ---          Minus 6 from c1
    >--- ---          Minus 6 from c2
    <<-                  Minus 1 from c0
]

>                      Moves to c1
[   
    >                   Moves to c2
    [
        >+              Increment c3 by 1
        >+              Increment c4 by 1
        <<-             decrement c2 by 1
    ]
    >                   move to c3
    [
        <+              increment c2
        >-              decrement c3
    ]
    <<-                  decrement c1 by 1
]

<++++ ++++              cell c0 = 8
[
    >>>>+++ +++        increment c5 by 6
    <<<<-              decrement c0 by 1
]
>>>>.                  print c4
```

my suggestion any line you write in BrainFuck always comment what it's doing